# How to enable 12-factor application bundling with Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Reading the Next.js documentation about [environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) -

> In order to keep server-only secrets safe, Next.js replaces process.env.* with the correct values at **build time**.

Does it mean that the environment variables available at **build time** are the only variables are available for Next.js application at runtime? This seems to be problematic as it means I will have to build for each environment!

And, if that is the case, how do I enable my application to adopt to [12-factor](https://12factor.net/) delivery? I want to package Next.js application as a Docker image which I must build **only** once and then deploy to three different environments - **test**, **staging** and then **production** on Azure PaaS.

Comment: Wow, this does indeed suck. It appears a lot of people seem to have gotten comfortable with (incorrectly, IMO) the concept of rebuilding apps as they move through envs.

Comment: @Adam Yeah. I agree. These are some age-old golden principles to follow and worst, the question itself gets closed :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sidecar proxy. [Istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/sidecar/) makes use of the pattern. There is nothing stopping you from directly using either envoy or [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/sidecar/) to implement the pattern.

You add a proxy that sits next to the nextjs app that accepts outgoing traffic and routes it to the correct API. Since the proxy has a local address, it can be addressed in the nextjs app statically and be reconfigured at a later time.

Comment: How does a sidecar proxy set variables for Next.js to use? I'm not sure how this answer addresses the question.

Comment: You specify a static configuration in the nextjs app that uses the local nginx, then you can configure nginx. This way you can at least configure outgoing traffic. Due to the extra complexity involved I would guess that most would opt for building env specific nextjs deployments.

Answer (score 0):

There's an in depth discussion of this very topic here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16995#discussioncomment-3176651

Personally I have the entrypoint of the container perform the build before starting, that way the environment variables can be taken  into account (which for me is especially important for SSG content).

I understand that some people are against this because the container startup time is impacted.

Comment: Yes. That's indeed one way to solve it but building before starting won't fall under the 12-factor definition.

Comment: It depends on your interpretation of what you are building. With Docker your building a container image, which is still the case. Also you can still pre-build the Next.js in the Dockefile stage which pulls down the node_modules and generates the Next cache, the subsequent "build on startup" phase is more about environment variables being swapped in and environment specific SSG content being consumed.

Comment: I've done a write up on this subject that compares and contrasts the various options you have available: http://www.craigwardman.com/Blogging/BlogEntry/ssg-isr-and-environment-variables-in-next-js-and-docker

Answer (score 0):

You can get runtime environment variables through `getServerSideProps` or by leveraging the App Router as explained in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying#environment-variables).